# Something I Can Use, that My Dua Becomes Accepted?

Tags: helping

Is there any homework I can do to get a dua answered? please give me instructions,
such as saying this dhikr this **x** amount of times for example
thank you

Comment: This is not how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Praying tahajjud (night prayer) is a very good option.

> Narrated by Uqba ibn Amir (R.A):
>
> “When one, out of two persons of my Ummah gets up at night and
>   motivates himself for Wudhu despite not feeling to do so since,
>   Shaytaan had tied knots on him. When he washes his two hands in Wudhu,
>   one knot is loosened, when he washes his face, another knot is
>   loosened when he wipes his head with wet hands another knot is
>   loosened, when he washes his feet yet another knot is loosened. Allah
>   Subhanahu Wa Ta’ala says to those behind the veil- His angels: “Look
>   at My slaves! How much hardship he is enduring in dealing with his
>   Nafs (inner self), so now whatever this slave asks of Me, it will be
>   granted to him.” (Ahmad)

Notice how Allah explicitly states that:

> **whatever** this slave asks of Me, it will be granted to him.

This therefore shows that praying during night-time is an excellent way of asking Allah for whatever you desire.

الله اعلم

Comment: isn' t tahajjud only in Ramadan , I can' t pray it today??

Comment: Nope, Taraweeh is in Ramadan. Tahajjud can be performed  any night and ishaAllah your du’as will bee accepted.

Comment: Also I heard this whats your view on this? https://islamqa.info/en/answers/143240/is-there-any-difference-between-tahajjud-and-qiyaam-al-layl

Comment: But how do i know I performed tahajjud instead of qiyam ul layl???

Comment: If you look at this https://islamqa.info/en/answers/143240/is-there-any-difference-between-tahajjud-and-qiyaam-al-layl It says tahajjud is actually tahajjud if you pray right away after waking up at night?

Comment: It’s the sunnah to pray tahajjud after waking up in the last third of the night and then pray witr at the end.

Comment: ->It is not stipulated that it should take up most of the night.  This line , it means in order for it to be tahajjud you have to pray the whole night ???? Qiyaam al-layl means spending the night, or part of it, even if it is only one hour, in prayer, reading Qur’aan, remembering Allah (dhikr) and other acts of worship. It is not stipulated that it should take up most of the night. <- its means the difference between quyan ul layl and tahajjud

Comment: No, it says it’s *not* stipulated that it should take the whole night. So it’s not necessary.

Comment: Qiyaam al-layl means spending the night, or part of it, even if it is only one hour, in prayer, reading Qur’aan, remembering Allah (dhikr) and other acts of worship. It is not stipulated that it should take up most of the night. <- for qiyam ul layl it is not stipulated but for tahajjud it is

Comment: so, that means I have to pray at night right when I wake up and most of the night for tahajjud?

Comment: Leave all your confusions. Just pray tahajjud at night, and inshaAllah your du’as will be accepted. It is also better for you to go to your local masjid so that a knowledgeable person can demonstrate how to pray tahajjud.

Comment: By the way, if your du’as are not seeming to have an effect, don’t be disheartened as Allah most certainly has a better plan for you.